# Client side custom validator for radio buttons

Tags: c#, javascript

I am facing problem regarding validating radiobutton at client side named as "male", "female". I dont want to use radiobutton list, Could anyone please check my code and rectify it? Thanks.

**Here is .aspx page:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

                function ClientValidate(source, e) {
                    if (document.getElementById("content_radmale").checked == true || document.getElementById("content_radfemale").checked == true) {
                        e.IsValid = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        e.IsValid = false;
                    }
                  //  alert("Enter gender  !");
                }
</script>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="please enter any option" ClientValidationFunction = "ClientValidate"
        ValidationGroup="gender" ControlToValidate="txtname"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

**And .cs page:**

```
    string gender = radmale.Text;

    if (radfemale.Checked)
    {
        gender = radfemale.Text;

    }
    CustomValidator1.Validate(); 
    string sql = "INSERT INTO registration(emailaddress,username,password,name,gender)VALUES ('"+email+"','"+username+"','"+pass+"','"+name+"','"+gender+"')  ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   con.Close();
```

Comment: please reply me as soon as possible

Comment: [Here](http://www.chennaisunday.com/jsradio.html) is an suitable example for you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not popular in asp but i know you can also add html in it. If you do not want to use a radio button you can use a select box like this.

HTML

```
<select id = "gender">
   <option value = 'm'>Male</option>
   <option value = 'f'>Female</option>
</select>
```

JQUERY

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
       //get the selected gender
      $('#gender').change(function() {
          var gender = $(this).val();
          alert(gender);
      });
   })
</script>
```

Comment: no actually i want to use radio button,, not radiolist,, and also i dnt want to validate through alert, through alert my code is working good, i want error message to be displayed just like displayed in case of other validators

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

JS

```
    function validateRadioButton() {
        var v1 = document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidator1");
        if ($('input:radio[name=Gender]').is(':checked') == false) {
            ValidatorEnable(v1, true);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            ValidatorEnable(v1, false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function ClientValidate(source, e) {
        e.IsValid = false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var v1 = document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidator1");
        ValidatorEnable(v1, false);
    });
```

ASPX

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Text="Male" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Text="Femlae" />
<div style="display: none;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate">jayesh goyani</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return validateRadioButton();" />
```

Comment: i need to use custom validator,, not required field validator